# Rails automatically update CSRF token for repeat JSON request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, security, csrf

I have a single page ROR app with lots of remote forms. My problem is, after a non-idempotent request Rails changes the CSRF token and invalidates the token embedded in the page meta. So that repeat non-indempotent request fails if the page isn't refreshed.

For example, when a remote form submitted via POST fails with validation errors and the form is resubmitted it fails with an InvalidAuthenticityToken error.

I would think this problem is common enough for Rails to handle it by default, but apparently not.

Comment: Can you make the CSRF token persist? You only really need one CSRF token per user session, not per "unsafe" request.

Comment: @SilverlightFox Does persisting the CSRF token not lower the apps security? Isn't it possible for an attacker to capture the CSRF token and use it in making request?

Comment: Not really, [see here](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/22936/8340). There is some risk for a [BREACH attack](http://breachattack.com/), however you're best off disabling any compression over HTTPS.

Comment: Just added my own answer there too: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/106826/8340

Answer (score 8):

My solution to this, any pitfalls here?:

application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  # callback to set CSRF TOKEN for non-idempotent Ajax request
  after_action :add_csrf_token_to_json_request_header

  private

  def add_csrf_token_to_json_request_header
    if request.xhr? && !request.get? && protect_against_forgery?
      response.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] = form_authenticity_token
    end
  end
end
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery2
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks=

$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  header_token = xhr.getResponseHeader('X-CSRF-Token');
  if (header_token) $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content', header_token)
});
```

Comment: Thank you. after one day of searching solution I ran into this and it works for me. my application disables turbolinks and since i have single page application I would need to handle the csrf by myself or i get the ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error